# Which LEGO AT-RT is this?

Tags: set-identification, star-wars

I made a LEGO AT-RT with the help of a video but I can't find it now. It looks like a clone scout walker but green and a bit different in design. I loved that AT-RT. I hope someone can help me find it. The legs look like the legs on the LEGO 75002 Walker:

[image: LEGO 75002]

Comment: If you watched this on youtube, how about digging through your history?  https://www.youtube.com/feed/history

Answer (score 3):

A quick search found these two video's of AT-RT's in green

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c0sFAreiaPc

and

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cbc_k_GwfRw

this AT-RT is also very nice and greenish (no video)

https://www.flickr.com/photos/legoarts/4917477074/in/photostream/

Comment: What i seen is bigger but thx for the help :D

Answer (score 2):

[image]

This may be the clone trooper you are searching for...

Answer (score 2):

Are you thinking of the 20th Anniversary AT-RT?  The legs are very similar but the head looks fairly different.  It is grey with sand green and tan accents.  The set number is [75261](https://brickset.com/sets/75261-1/Clone-Scout-Walker-%E2%80%93-20th-Anniversary-Edition).

[image]